# Why can you call some methods without parentheses while for others you must use parentheses (Kotlin)?

Tags: generics, kotlin

In the example below, why is it that I can invoke nums.lastIndex WITHOUT using parentheses (ex. nums.lastIndex) while for nums.isEmpty() I need to use parentheses?

```
fun removeDuplicates(nums: IntArray): Int {
    if(nums.isEmpty()) return 0
    var forwardCounter = 0
    var newArrayIndex = 0
    while(forwardCounter != nums.lastIndex) {
        if(nums[newArrayIndex] < nums[forwardCounter + 1]) {
            newArrayIndex += 1
            nums[newArrayIndex] = nums[forwardCounter + 1]
        }
    forwardCounter += 1
    }
    return newArrayIndex + 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because [`lastIndex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-index.html) is a property while [`isEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-empty.html) is a function.

Note that Java no-arg getter and single-arg setter methods can be mapped to Kotlin properties and [invoked with the property syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html).